# How to create an Angular directive that takes iFrame as an input?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular9

I am working on an Angular form that contains input fields like Amount, Credit card number, Expiry date, and CVV and it looks like this[image: picture]

What is the main ask: Credit card number input is being taken from a 3rd party library and hence the UI/layout of the credit card field looks different than the other fields(Amount, Expiry Date, and CVV). These 3 fields are built using `<mat-form-field>` tag and look [image: like this when focussed, ie they are taking up the angular/material styles]

What I wanted to achieve is the exact same layout for the card number field(similar to other fields). What would be the best approach to do that?

Shall I write a structural/attribute directive that wraps an iFrame and attach the directive to the `<mat-form-field>` so that field gets the styling from angular/material cdk

Quick background: The credit card input field is an input field that is inside an iframe. [image: The blue highlighted part is an iFrame]

Comment: have you got any solution on this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.